# Spring Data JPA NativeQuery like search

Tags: java, spring, orm, spring-data-jpa

I have tried this query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT distinct `id`,`customer name`,`customer number` FROM My_Data WHERE `customer number` like '%"
        + ":customerNumber" + "%'", nativeQuery = true)
public List<MyData> findDistinctByCustomerNumberContainingIgnoreCase(
        @Param("customerNumber") String customerNumber);
```

When I run this,
I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1]
>   did not exist exception.

I want a native query due to some restrictions I have with my table.

Comment: show the method signature

Comment: @MaciejKowalski updated the question with method signature now.

Answer (score 1):

You have put the placeholder within parentheses and the engine treats it like a plain string.

If you surround it simply with %, the engine will know to parse that adding the parentherses in the resolved query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT distinct `id`,`customer name`,`customer number` FROM My_Data 
       WHERE `customer number` like %:customerNumber%", nativeQuery = true)
```